# UWP , Why Sideload package can not include PDF files?

Tags: uwp

I put my software manual (PDF) at Assets/manual folder.

and I make Sideload application package. and I confirm installed folder.
There is No PDF and folder "manual".

Why ?

Here is my step.

1. in VisualStduio, I open Assets/manual folder.
2. Copy all file to the folder.
3. Include the PDF into Assets/manual with VisutalStuido.
4. In DEBUG mode, I copy manual folder to "bin\x64\Debug\AppX\Assets\manual" manually.
5. In Release mode, I also copy to "bin\x64\Release\AppX\Assets\manual" , manually.

What wrong ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set BuildAction=Content on the PDF to make them part of the package output. Then it will work automatically in VS when you deploy the app or create the package.

[image]